# R Highcharter customize legend to show only certain values

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, legend, r-highcharter

I need the legend to show candidate names and their colors where interval == 3.
[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVL6M.png)

Subsetting the stops df (stops[my.cols$interval==3])) works for the legend, but it also changes the colors on the map. I need to keep the colors on each state the same, but I don't want to show a candidate's name more than once in the legend.

See MWE below:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(usmap)
library(dplyr)

df <- usmap::statepop
df$interval <- sample(c(1,2,3), nrow(df), replace = T)
df$scaled <- sample(1:18, nrow(df), replace = T)

us_small <- download_map_data("countries/us/custom/us-small")


my.cols <- data.frame(
  interval = c(3,2,1),
  scaled = 1:18,
  ContractName = c(rep("Klobuchar",3),rep("Buttigieg",3),rep("Bloomberg",3),rep("Biden",3),rep("Sanders",3),rep("Warren",3)),
  hexes = c(  # GRAY: [
    '#dddddd',
    '#bbbbbb',
    '#888888',
    # PURPLE: [
    '#e8bbdc',
    '#b577a5' ,
    '#7c466e' ,
    # GREEN: [
    '#bbe8ae',
    '#88b57a',
    '#4e7641',
    # BLUE: [
    '#b5cacf',
    '#81b5c0',
    '#578b96' ,
    # RED: [
    '#f9adad',
    '#cf0000',
    '#9f0000',
    # more gray
    "#000000",
    "#696969",
    "#808080"
  ))

stops <- data.frame(
  name = my.cols$ContractName,
  scaled = 1:18,
  from = 0:17/17,
  color = toupper(my.cols$hexes),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- merge(df, stops, by = "scaled")

stops <- list_parse(stops) 




highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(us_small, df,
                    value = "from", joinBy = c("woe-name", "full"),
                    borderColor = "darkgrey"
                    ,dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE
                                       ,format = "{point.properties.hc-a2}")) %>% 
  # hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = stops[my.cols$interval==3]) %>%
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = stops) %>%
  hc_legend(align = 'right') %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = FALSE)
```

Is there something in hc_plotOptions that can help customize the legend?

This solution grays out the repeated names in the legend, but still shows them: [R - highcharter - selective legends at display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447985/r-highcharter-selective-legends-at-display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the seed:

```
set.seed(111)
df <- usmap::statepop
df$interval <- sample(c(1,2,3), nrow(df), replace = T)
df$scaled <- sample(1:18, nrow(df), replace = T)
```

You subset stops according to the data.frame my.cols? Before it looks like this:

[image]

Hope I got your correct, because it's not very clear which legends you want to display:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(us_small, df,
                    value = "from", joinBy = c("woe-name", "full"),
                    borderColor = "darkgrey",
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE
                                       ,format = "{point.properties.hc-a2}")) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = stops[my.cols$interval==3]) %>%
  hc_legend(align = 'right') %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = FALSE)
```

[image]

These are the packages in my session used to run this:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

[...]

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.3       usmap_0.5.0       highcharter_0.7.0
```

Comment: Sub-setting the stops data.frame changes the colors up in the map as well. I need to keep the colors in the map consistent but only show each candidate's name once in the legend.

Comment: I will clarify the original post now

Comment: Hey I have no idea what you are referring too.. maybe you sort it out first.. to me, all the colors look the same, only the legend changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing because when I run the same code with/without the subset the colors on my states change. I will accept your answer because it seems to work for you, but I'll wait a little bit to see if anybody else has the same problem I do when running the MWE above.

Comment: no worries. I find it odd thats all. I have updated the answer with the versions I am using, and the packages. See if you can reproduce it

Comment: I forgot that I was randomly sampling in my MWE, so my states were changing colors because I re-ran the sampling. Thank you! Sorry it took me a bit...

Comment: You're welcome :) That was something that crossed my mind today when I tried to reproduce the plot